# Example of second order homogeneous differential equation that has exactly one bounded solution, but inhomogeneous does not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A function $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is bounded if there exists an $M>0$ such that $|x(t)|<M$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that if a second order linear homogeneous differential equation has exactly one bounded solution, then the inhomogeneous equation must also have exactly one?

I don't think so, but I can't come up with an example. Can you give me one?

Comment: If $y$ is a bounded solution of a linear homogeneous differential equation, then so is $C\,y$ for any constant $C$. Your assumption of uniqueness never holds.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre You are right, but maybe somebody can still think of something.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre See fibonatic's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for a second order linear homogeneous differential equation can be written as

$$
x(t) = c_1 x_1(t) + c_2 x_2(t) + x_p(t),
$$

where $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are general solutions to the homogeneous differential equation, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants which can be solved for with the initial conditions and $x_p(t)$ is the particular solution, which satisfies the inhomogeneity.

When there is exactly one solution to the homogeneous differential equation, then both $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ have to be unbounded, such that only $c_1=c_2=0$ yields a bounded solution. From this one can also conclude that there is also only one solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation, namely just $x_p(t)$, however this does not ensures that it will also be bounded, so there might be none.

For example take the differential equation

$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t) - x(t) = t,
$$

has the general solution

$$
x(t) = c_1 e^{-t} + c_2 e^{t} - t.
$$

The only bounded solution to the homogeneous differential equation is $x(t)=0$ and therefore the only solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation is $x(t)=-t$, which is not bounded for $\forall\;t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example where the particular solution is not bounded

Comment: @TonyStrong see my edit.